# Animating a canvas object in Fragment From Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, canvas

okay, I have an Activity which is divided into 4 Fragments and in topMost Fragment I used a canvas to Draw a triangle using Path.

In the middle Fragment I have a view Pager, I am searching for a way to animate the triangle from the viewPager onPageScrolled().
Code

**Fragment**

```
public class LoginTopCanvas extends Fragment {
private View topCanvasView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    topCanvasView = new PagerCanvasTop(getActivity());
    return topCanvasView;
}
```

}

**Canvas**

```
public class PagerCanvasTop extends View {
private String TAG = "PagerCanvasTop";
Paint redPaint;
Canvas canvas;
public PagerCanvasTop(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bb_red));

    Paint blackPaint = new Paint();
    blackPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bb_black));
    blackPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    redPaint = new Paint();
    redPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bb_red));
    redPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    redPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    Paint bluePaint = new Paint();
    bluePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    int screenWidth = this.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = this.getHeight();

    canvas.drawCircle(screenWidth / 2, -((screenWidth * 2) - (screenWidth / 15)), (screenWidth * 2), blackPaint);

    //Triangle


    float mid = getWidth() / 2;
    float min = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());
    float fat = min / 17;
    float half = min / 2;

    redPaint.setStrokeWidth(fat);
    redPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    redPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    drawTriangle(mid, 35, half - 10, 30, 0);
    canvas.drawCircle(mid, half - 10, 2, bluePaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(mid-35, half+15, 2, bluePaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(mid + 35, half + 15, 2, bluePaint);



    super.onDraw(canvas);

}

public void drawTriangle(float x, int deltaX, float y, int deltaY, float deltaMove) {

    **//this is the triangle which I want to animate**

    Path path = new Path();
    path.reset();
    path.moveTo(x, y+deltaMove);
    path.lineTo(x - deltaX, y + deltaY);
    path.lineTo(x + deltaX, y + deltaY);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, redPaint);

}
}
```

**Activity**

In activity I have a view Pager with addOnPageChangeListener.From the on PageScrolled() I want to animate the drawn traingle. How will i access the object drawn in canvas which is in a fragment from myactivty

Directly calling the drawTriangle() and pass a new Canvas() giving me a NullpointerException

Help and advises needed
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middle fragment should set an `OnPageChangeListener` on the `ViewPager` than will call an interface method on the activity in `onPageScrolled`.

Your activity should implement some interface for page scrolling.  You can make your own custom interface or just reuse the `OnPageChangeListener` interface.  The implementation should get a reference to your top fragment (either save a reference after creating it or calling `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()`) and call a method on the top fragment to set the `onPageScrolled` value.

Your top fragment should define a method similar to `onPageScrolled` that can accept the page scroll value from the activity and store it, then call `invalidate()` on the fragment's view.

Your top fragment should have a property like `private float mPosition` that stores the last position value.

Then in your top fragment `onDraw`, refer to the `mPosition` property when you draw the triangle.